# How can I access my settings.settings names arbitrarily?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, settings.settings

Finding this one hard to explain...

I am storing around 80 settings in usersettings, the majority of which are stored as ints.

I am in the process of rewriting a pre-existing program to implement MVVM, and whilst I could just pull the current code out and put it where it needs to go etc, I know there is a better way of handling this but am unsure how to do so.

I will leave a sample of some code working with many oif these settings... I think I need a something which can take a parameter, and form the name of the setting based on the attribute given...

This is some of the code... Instead of repeating the same code over and over again, I want some way of doing this a totally different way?

```
Regex overallRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){0}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //These statements regex out the rank, level and xp.
Match overallStats = overallRgx.Match(str);
Regex attackRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){1}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match attackStats = attackRgx.Match(str);
Regex defenceRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){2}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match defenceStats = defenceRgx.Match(str);
Regex strengthRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){3}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match strengthStats = strengthRgx.Match(str);
Regex constitutionRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){4}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match constitutionStats = constitutionRgx.Match(str);
Regex rangeRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){5}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match rangeStats = rangeRgx.Match(str);
Regex prayerRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){6}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match prayerStats = prayerRgx.Match(str);
Regex magicRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){7}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match magicStats = magicRgx.Match(str);
Regex cookingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){8}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match cookingStats = cookingRgx.Match(str);
Regex woodcuttingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){9}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match woodcuttingStats = woodcuttingRgx.Match(str);
Regex fletchingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){10}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match fletchingStats = fletchingRgx.Match(str);
Regex fishingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){11}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match fishingStats = fishingRgx.Match(str);
Regex firemakingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){12}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match firemakingStats = firemakingRgx.Match(str);
Regex craftingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){13}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match craftingStats = craftingRgx.Match(str);
Regex smithingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){14}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match smithingStats = smithingRgx.Match(str);
Regex miningRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){15}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match miningStats = miningRgx.Match(str);
Regex herbloreRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){16}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match herbloreStats = herbloreRgx.Match(str);
Regex agilityRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){17}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match agilityStats = agilityRgx.Match(str);
Regex thievingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){18}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match thievingStats = thievingRgx.Match(str);
Regex slayerRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){19}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match slayerStats = slayerRgx.Match(str);
Regex farmingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){20}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match farmingStats = farmingRgx.Match(str);
Regex runecraftingRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){21}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match runecraftingStats = runecraftingRgx.Match(str);
Regex hunterRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){22}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match hunterStats = hunterRgx.Match(str);
Regex constructionRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){23}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match constructionStats = constructionRgx.Match(str);
Regex summoningRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){24}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match summoningStats = summoningRgx.Match(str);
Regex dungeoneeringRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){25}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match dungeoneeringStats = dungeoneeringRgx.Match(str);
Regex divinationRgx = new Regex(@"(?:.+?\n){26}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match divinationStats = divinationRgx.Match(str);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettUsername = DisplayName.Text;

Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallRank = Convert.ToInt32(overallStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverall = Convert.ToInt32(overallStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallXP = Convert.ToString(overallStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackRank = Convert.ToInt32(attackStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttack = Convert.ToInt32(attackStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackXP = Convert.ToInt32(attackStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceRank = Convert.ToInt32(defenceStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefence = Convert.ToInt32(defenceStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceXP = Convert.ToInt32(defenceStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthRank = Convert.ToInt32(strengthStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrength = Convert.ToInt32(strengthStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthXP = Convert.ToInt32(strengthStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionRank = Convert.ToInt32(constitutionStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitution = Convert.ToInt32(constitutionStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionXP = Convert.ToInt32(constitutionStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeRank = Convert.ToInt32(rangeStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettRange = Convert.ToInt32(rangeStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeXP = Convert.ToInt32(rangeStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerRank = Convert.ToInt32(prayerStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayer = Convert.ToInt32(prayerStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerXP = Convert.ToInt32(prayerStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicRank = Convert.ToInt32(magicStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagic = Convert.ToInt32(magicStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicXP = Convert.ToInt32(magicStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingRank = Convert.ToInt32(cookingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettCooking = Convert.ToInt32(cookingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingXP = Convert.ToInt32(cookingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingRank = Convert.ToInt32(woodcuttingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcutting = Convert.ToInt32(woodcuttingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingXP = Convert.ToInt32(woodcuttingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingRank = Convert.ToInt32(fletchingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletching = Convert.ToInt32(fletchingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingXP = Convert.ToInt32(fletchingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingRank = Convert.ToInt32(fishingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishing = Convert.ToInt32(fishingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingXP = Convert.ToInt32(fishingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingRank = Convert.ToInt32(firemakingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremaking = Convert.ToInt32(firemakingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingXP = Convert.ToInt32(firemakingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingRank = Convert.ToInt32(craftingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettCrafting = Convert.ToInt32(craftingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingXP = Convert.ToInt32(craftingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingRank = Convert.ToInt32(smithingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithing = Convert.ToInt32(smithingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingXP = Convert.ToInt32(smithingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningRank = Convert.ToInt32(miningStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettMining = Convert.ToInt32(miningStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningXP = Convert.ToInt32(miningStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreRank = Convert.ToInt32(herbloreStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerblore = Convert.ToInt32(herbloreStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreXP = Convert.ToInt32(herbloreStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityRank = Convert.ToInt32(agilityStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgility = Convert.ToInt32(agilityStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityXP = Convert.ToInt32(agilityStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingRank = Convert.ToInt32(thievingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettThieving = Convert.ToInt32(thievingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingXP = Convert.ToInt32(thievingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerRank = Convert.ToInt32(slayerStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayer = Convert.ToInt32(slayerStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerXP = Convert.ToInt32(slayerStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingRank = Convert.ToInt32(farmingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarming = Convert.ToInt32(farmingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingXP = Convert.ToInt32(farmingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingRank = Convert.ToInt32(runecraftingStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecrafting = Convert.ToInt32(runecraftingStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingXP = Convert.ToInt32(runecraftingStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterRank = Convert.ToInt32(hunterStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunter = Convert.ToInt32(hunterStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterXP = Convert.ToInt32(hunterStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionRank = Convert.ToInt32(constructionStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstruction = Convert.ToInt32(constructionStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionXP = Convert.ToInt32(constructionStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningRank = Convert.ToInt32(summoningStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoning = Convert.ToInt32(summoningStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningXP = Convert.ToInt32(summoningStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringRank = Convert.ToInt32(dungeoneeringStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneering = Convert.ToInt32(dungeoneeringStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringXP = Convert.ToInt32(dungeoneeringStats.Groups[3].Value);

Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationRank = Convert.ToInt32(divinationStats.Groups[1].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivination = Convert.ToInt32(divinationStats.Groups[2].Value);
Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationXP = Convert.ToInt32(divinationStats.Groups[3].Value);
```

Also, used again to set text places (this will need to change to databinding now of course)

```
switch (skill)
{
    case "Overall":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Convert.ToInt64(Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallXP));

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt64(exp[i]) < Convert.ToInt64(Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallXP))
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = Convert.ToInt64(exp[nextLevel]) - Convert.ToInt64(Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallXP);
        percent = Convert.ToInt64(Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallXP) - Convert.ToInt64(exp[realLevel]);
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettOverallRank;
        break;

    case "Attack":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettAttackRank;
        break;

    case "Defence":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDefenceRank;
        break;

    case "Strength":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettStrengthRank;
        break;

    case "Constitution":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstitutionRank;
        break;

    case "Range":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettRangeRank;
        break;

    case "Prayer":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettPrayerRank;
        break;

    case "Magic":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettMagicRank;
        break;

    case "Cooking":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettCookingRank;
        break;

    case "Woodcutting":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettWoodcuttingRank;
        break;

    case "Fletching":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFletchingRank;
        break;

    case "Fishing":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFishingRank;
        break;

    case "Firemaking":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFiremakingRank;
        break;

    case "Crafting":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettCraftingRank;
        break;

    case "Smithing":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSmithingRank;
        break;

    case "Mining":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettMiningRank;
        break;

    case "Herblore":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettHerbloreRank;
        break;

    case "Agility":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettAgilityRank;
        break;

    case "Thieving":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettThievingRank;
        break;

    case "Slayer":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSlayerRank;
        break;

    case "Farming":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettFarmingRank;
        break;

    case "Runecrafting":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettRunecraftingRank;
        break;

    case "Hunter":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettHunterRank;
        break;

    case "Construction":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettConstructionRank;
        break;

    case "Summoning":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettSummoningRank;
        break;

    case "Dungeoneering":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDungeoneeringRank;
        break;

    case "Divination":
        SkillRank.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationRank);
        SkillXP.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationXP);

        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] < Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationXP)
            {
                realLevel = i;
            }
        }
        nextLevel = realLevel + 1;
        required = exp[nextLevel] - Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationXP;
        percent = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationXP - exp[realLevel];
        rank = Properties.Settings.Default.SettDivinationRank;
        break;

    default:
        exp[0] = 3;
        realLevel = 1;
        percent = 1;
        break;
}
```

So essentially... Would there be a way that I could pass a parameter somewhere, of say "Attack" and it would do what it needs to do with attack everywhere... Then pass a parameter of "Defence" and it does what it needs to do etc... It would be cool if there was a way, for example of doing this:

```
string str = "attack";
Properties.Settings.Default. + str  = "blah";
```

Comment: Instead of declaring one line then using it the next you can cut your code in half by just doing `Match overallStats = Regx.Match(str, @"(?:.+?\n){0}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Thats one thing, but would there be a way of shortening it much further, by passing a parameter somewhere? so sort of "this is the little nugget of code which is repeated, do it with this setting, now with this setting, etc"